# Android API-Demo MediaPlayer not playing videos from SD-Card

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I installed the ApiDemos project, which can be found in `<your-sdk-path>/sdk/samples` (provided you installed samples with SDK manager). I tried the one for api17. I pushed a video file onto the sd card of my device (I tried a samsung tablet and a LG P990) with DDMS and set the Path of the video to:

```
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myvideo.mp4";
```

(That is the only part where I edited the ApiDemos example)

I checked that this path returns the actual path to the sdcard where I pushed to file to and it is, the video however is not played.

When I run the whole thing in a genymotion device, the video is played without a problem. Does anyone has an Idea whats wrong here?

### Log

These are the lines that are logged when the video is tried to be loaded by the ApiDemo:

```
11-05 16:03:42.830    2305-2334/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-05 16:03:42.838   2305-10023/? E/OMXCodec﹕ [LEGO] else flags = 0
11-05 16:03:42.955   2305-10023/? E/OMXCodec﹕ set buffer size variable to : 1572864
11-05 16:03:44.970   2305-10034/? E/OMXCodec﹕ [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] ERROR(0x80001000, 0)
11-05 16:03:45.189      385-456/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ set default RSSI: -200
11-05 16:03:46.986   2305-10023/? A/OMXCodec﹕ frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp:1821 CHECK_EQ( err,(status_t)OK) failed: -110 vs. 0
11-05 16:03:46.986   2305-10023/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 10023 (TimedEventQueue)
```

Comment: Are there no errors or warnings in logcat that seem relevant?

Answer (score 0):

If your Video is in the root of your sd Card then try:

```
videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
```

or try if you have a Directory named e.g "my_Videos"

```
path =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//my_Videos//"; 
path += "myvideo.mp4";
```

Comment: Exactly this is not working. The same thing happens in the api demo

Comment: Check your Android Manifest file for Permission:    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />